# ExtJS: Store loads without parameters

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I'm upgrading to ExtJS 5 and can't solve this issue. I've got a function that manages everything after the login and loads store after login with the new parameters from login.

```
...
Ext.create('MyApp.store.MainStore').load({
        params: {
            auth: sessionStorage.authSessionId,
            hostname: sessionStorage.hostname
        },
        callback: function(records, operation, success) {
            //some callback
        }
})
...
```

However this loads the store, but without parameters, which causes an error on server side.
My store definition:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MainStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    storeId: 'MainStore',
    autoSync: false,
    autoLoad: false,

    proxy   : {
        type : 'ajax',
        url  : '/menu',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'children',
        },
        listeners : {
                exception : function(proxy, response, operation) {
                    //exception handling
                }
            }
    },
    fields: ['labelText','dbName','corpName','isLeaf', 'page']

});
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring a root node on your store definition.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MainStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    storeId: 'MainStore',
    autoSync: false,
    autoLoad: false,

    proxy   : {
        type : 'ajax',
        url  : '/menu',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'children',
        },
        listeners : {
                exception : function(proxy, response, operation) {
                    //exception handling
                }
            }
    },
    fields: ['labelText','dbName','corpName','isLeaf', 'page'],
    root: {}

});
```

Comment: that worked, 
but i still don't understand it, could you please explain it to me?

Comment: EDIT: this loads the page but the store is empty, can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. If you call `load` on an empty TreeStore, it will load just fine, *but* it won't pay attention to any options you passed in, such as the parameters.

Setting a root node first allows the load to work - but then, as you've seen, you can't use it in a TreePanel (and why else would you have a TreeStore). Kind of silly, huh?

I reported this to Sencha - http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?288818-5.0.0.970-TreeStore.load()-doesn-t-call-callback-if-there-is-no-root-node.

As for workarounds:

- you can provide the parameters by using the `params` configuration on the proxy. Annoying, but it does work. (Actually, `extraParams` might be the better choice, as it allows you to preserve the authentication token and change the main parameters if and when you use `reload`).
- you can get the callback by using event handling.

BTW, because you're using `autoLoad: false`, you'll need to load the store at some point. Do that *before* you add it to the TreePanel - the only way to get a root node that works with the TreePanel seems to be to get the TreePanel to make it for you.